Git clone not working on windows dev drive
I started using Windows 11 Dev drive. After I created a separate dev drive, I was not able to clone my repositories into my dev drive. I tried cloning into other drives and it works correctly. Dev drive uses the Resilient File System (ReFS) file system.
Here is the error I got after running git clone Myrepo
Receiving objects:   7% (5082/67583), 9.81 MiB | 52.00 KiB/s
Receiving objects:   7% (5085/67583), 10.37 MiB | 128.00 KiB/s
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 5 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
error: 5360 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output


Are you behind a proxy or something similar?

@evolutionxbox No, As I mentioned on other drives, it is working properly. There might be an issue with the file system.
